# ¿Cuándo comenzó a usarse en España "do" como sustitución de "ut"?

Tags: historia, españa, música

Leo en el *Autoridades* de 1739:

> SOLFA. s.f. Arte, que enseña à reducir à conforme unidad, ò consonancia las voces entre sí diversas: es lo mismo que Música, y tiene seis voces: que son *ut, re, mi, fa, sol, la*.

Llama la atención que por entonces había seis notas, y no siete. Pero llama igualmente la atención el hecho de que la nota *do* se llamara por entonces *ut*. Buscando en el diccionario veo que no fue hasta 1869 que la RAE especificó en el diccionario que *ut* estaba ya obsoleta y que su nombre actual era *do*.

Sin embargo, buscando en la Wikipedia se ve que el cambio de *ut* a *do*, realizado meramente por motivos de facilidad de pronunciación, lo hizo [Giovanni Battista Doni](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Battista_Doni) en el siglo XVII (murió en 1647), mucho antes de la redacción del *Autoridades*.

Por supuesto, el cambio pudo tardar en llegar a España, pero me extraña que no fuera hasta pasados dos siglos que la RAE registrara ese hecho. Pregunto pues: ¿cuándo comenzó a usarse en España *do* como nota musical en vez del antiguo *ut*? ¿De qué registros disponemos en nuestra literatura que puedan probar su uso antes de la edición de 1869 o incluso del *Autoridades*?

Comment: El autor que estudio tuvo la fama de tener el primer libro de teoría de música en castellano dedicado a él. Voy a ver si puedo encontrar una copia del libro para ver qué se usaba en este primer texto (ojo: si hace falta un préstamo interbibliotecario igual tardo meses en contestar jaja)

Answer (score 3):

No encuentro muchos casos en el CORDE como para sacar conclusiones, pero en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España sí que se pueden consultar muchos documentos buscando las cadenas "ut re mi" y "do re mi". Expongo los resultados:

- **Ut**: apenas se encuentran una centena de resultados entre todos los registros. Algunos a finales del siglo XVIII y la mayoría en el XIX, en textos que citan las notas como algo actual, de la época, pero ya en textos de finales del siglo XIX y ya los del XX se usa *ut* como algo obsoleto, para indicar que era el nombre antiguo de la nota, o como documentación histórica ("tiempo después, Guido de Arezzo aplicó a su escala los nombres de ut, re, mi, fa", 31/3/1914).
- **Do**: hay más de diez mil resultados en la hemeroteca. Los primeros son cuatro casos en el *Diario de Madrid* en 1800, luego un par de casos más también en Madrid en la década de 1820, y ya de forma más consistente en el resto del país a partir de 1840.

Así que al parecer conforme fue avanzando el siglo XIX se fue produciendo la transición paulatina de *ut* a *do*, tal y como se refleja en los periódicos y revistas de la época. Luego si a partir de 1840 fue cuando parece que *do* comenzó a ganar terreno en España frente a *ut*, resulta pues plausible que en 1852 la RAE aún mostrara *ut* como nombre de la primera nota musical (sin indicar que estuviera obsoleta), y en 1869 ya sí que indicara su estado de "nombre antiguo".

Curiosamente, no fue la RAE la pionera en indicar esto. Fue el *Gaspar y Roig* de 1855 quien lo indicó en primer lugar:

> **UT** : s. m. Mús. : nombre que dió Guido Aretino a la primera escala natural, y una de las sílabas que se usaron para el solfeo, la cual fue sustituida después por el DO por ser de más dulce pronunciación.

La voz *ut* permaneció en el diccionario de la RAE hasta 1992. En la versión de 2001 ya había desaparecido, aunque aún se puede ver en la etimología de la entrada para *[fa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HR36rG7)*:

> Del lat. UT *queant laxis* RE*sonare fibris* —MI*ra gestorum* FA*muli tuorum,* —SOL*ve polluti* LA*bii reatum*…, primera estrofa del himno de San Juan Bautista de la que Guido Aretino sacó el nombre de las seis notas de la escala musical de su tiempo.